# GitSmartHTTP for gitolite repositories over Apache does not allow me to push

Tags: apache, virtualhost, gitolite, smart-http, git-http-backend

I am setting up a git-http-backend CGI script to handle my `git.domain` subdomain. The server is behind an ELB (elastic load balancer) on AWS cloud. My server config is as follows (my git hosting is handled by gitolite):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.domain
    ServerAdmin hjpotter92+git@domain

    #SuexecUserGroup git git                                                                                                                                                                    
    DocumentRoot /opt/gitolite/repositories/

    PerlLoadModule Apache::Authn::Redmine

    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/gitolite/repositories/
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER # Have also tried removing this variable
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

    ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \                                                                                                                                                                    
           info/refs | \                                                                                                                                                                        
           objects/(info/[^/]+ | \                                                                                                                                                              
           [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \                                                                                                                                                         
           pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \                                                                                                                                              
           git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
        /opt/gitolite/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

    <Directory "/opt/gitolite/git-core">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -Includes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location />
        # enabled in desparation...
        # saw it somewhere in bugzilla powered mailing list
        DAV On

        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Repositories"
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        Require valid-user

        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com"
        RedmineDbUser "user"
        RedmineDbPass "your"
        RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
    </Location>

    LogLevel info
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitolite.access.log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/gitolite.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache server is run by the `www-data:www-data` user/group, and the gitolite is setup with the `git:git` user/group. To allow apache to read/write to the repositories, I have done:

```
# usermod -a -G git www-data
// and as a desparate measure, in frustration, the following:
# usermod -a -G www-data git
```

The `PerlAccessHandler` and user auth is working perfectly, because I am able to clone my repositories using valid set of credentials from the redmine setup.

However, when I try to push; I get the following in the server logs:

```
10.0.225.176 [11/Feb/2017:07:46:26 +0530] "GET /xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 726 "-" "git/2.11.0"
10.0.225.176 [11/Feb/2017:07:46:27 +0530] "GET /xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 725 "-" "git/2.11.0"
10.0.225.176 [11/Feb/2017:07:46:27 +0530] "GET /xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 848 "-" "git/2.11.0"
10.0.225.176 [11/Feb/2017:07:46:27 +0530] "POST /xxx.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 130408 "-" "git/2.11.0"
```

and in the client side (the following appears after whatever connection timeout I have set in my load balancer, 30 sec to 10 min):

```
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 930 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

More often than not, I also have `POST` to `git-upload-pack` of length 0 (for the same command of the same repository with the same commit)

```
10.0.225.222 [11/Feb/2017:07:50:55 +0530] "POST /pandorica.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "git/2.11.0"
10.0.225.222 [11/Feb/2017:07:53:21 +0530] "POST /pandorica.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "git/2.11.0"
```

and receive the following in my server error logs:

```
[core:error] [pid 1683] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.0.225.176:2534] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
[cgid:error] [pid 1683] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.0.225.176:2534] AH02550: Failed to flush CGI output to client
```

I have even played with setuid and setuid for the git user, hoping that it might help me push to a repository; but to no avail!

```
chmod u+s /opt/gitolite/repositories
chmod g+s /opt/gitolite/repositories
// and the same commands for `*.git` inside `repositories`
```

The git config from inside the `/opt/gitolite/repositories/xyz.git/`:

```
http.postbuffer=200M
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=true
redminegitolite.projectid=xxx
http.receivepack=true
http.uploadpack=true
```

---

For references, I have already been through each of the following:

1. [git-http-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7222992/1190388)
2. [Apache and git-http-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25995863/1190388)
3. [How to set up git over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26734933/1190388)
4. [Setting Up git-http-backend with apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40924641/1190388)
5. [Setting up Git Server on Windows With git-http-backend.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3817478/1190388)

---

How do I setup the Apache VHost such that it starts accepting `git push`.

Comment: You might need to hard code the timeout value in Apache `mod_proxy_fcgi`.

Comment: @Shravan40 Not using fcgi at all. It is using plain old cgid.

Comment: If you don't mind, it would be helpful formulating your question so that it ends with a question. I am not sure if I can help, though, but Git doesnt seem to be your problem, so you could probably also remove that tag.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @bioffe no `git push` still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while. In my case it was permissions. I configured my docker engine process to run containers as non-root. *--userns-remap*

I have

```
#/etc/subuid 
docker-user:100000:65536

#/etc/subgid 
docker-runner:100000:65536

#/etc/passwd
docker-user:x:90:90::/home/docker-user:/sbin/nologin
dockremap:x:220:220::/home/dockremap:/bin/false
docker-root:x:100000:2::/home/docker-root:/sbin/nologin
docker-daemon:x:100001:2::/home/docker-daemon:/sbin/nologin
```

Just use this command:

```
setfacl -RL -m g:100000:rwx -m g:100002:rwx /var/git
```